# How to figure out boot disk from bcdedit?

Tags: windows, command-line, boot, raid, bcdedit

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 software mirror.

I boot from volume c:.

When i use:

```
bcdedit
```

I can see 3 different "Windows Boot Loader" entries with "device partition=C:". How can I figure out which boot entry is related to which physical disk?

```
Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {77777777-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows Server 2008 R2 - secondary plex
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \windows
resumeobject            {55555555-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb}
nx                      OptOut
detecthal               Yes

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {99999999-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows Server 2008 R2 - secondary plex
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \windows
resumeobject            {55555555-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb}
nx                      OptOut
detecthal               Yes

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {eeeeeeee-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows Server 2008 R2 - secondary plex - secondary plex
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \windows
resumeobject            {55555555-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb}
nx                      OptOut
detecthal               Yes
```

Comment: did your problem solved? or no ? is my answer helpful? +1 it please

Comment: @ saber tabatabaee yazdi : its not. I commented under Your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use the undocumented `/raw` flag when running `bcdedit /enum`.

Instead of printing `unknown`, `partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1` or `partition=C:` you will see output such as `PartEx 6500000 HD MBR Sig:1a2b3c4d`. This is showing you what is *actually* recorded in the BCD, as opposed to an *interpretation* of the data given currently accessible disks/partitions/filesystems.

The meaning in this case is "find the MBR disk with signature `1a2b3c4d` and then look for the partition starting at byte offset `0x6500000`".

There are other possible formats, for instance if your entry refers to a partition on a disk with a GPT partition table it will probably refer to the partition UUID.

(My heartfelt thanks to [SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/bcdedit.html) which is the only place on the entire internet that documents this `/raw` flag. My heartfelt *curses* to Microsoft for failing to document this vital diagnostic option to `bcdedit`!).

Comment: Any idea in which version of Windows `/raw` was introduced? Windows 7 bcdedit seems to lack it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open a command prompt with administrator privileges.
2. Run the following set of commands:

   ```
   DISKPART
   SELECT DISK 0
   UNIQUEID DISK ID=<random_disk_signature>
   ```

   (`<random_disk_signature>` is e.g. 1a2b3c4d)
3. Quit `DISKPART`, but stay in the command prompt.
4. Enter the following commands, one at a time, in the command prompt pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key after each command:

   ```
   bcdboot c:\windows /s c:
   bcdedit /set {DEFAULT.EN_US} device partition=c:
   bcdedit /set {DEFAULT.EN_US} osdevice partition=c:
   bcdedit /set {BOOTMGR.EN_US} device partition=c:
   ```
5. Close the command prompt.
6. Reboot.

Comment: @ saber tabatabaee yazdi : You can edit Your previous answer.

Comment: @rumburak : ok but deleting that seems much more better ..

Comment: @ saber tabatabaee yazdi : How should I get boot disk with this ?

Comment: i'm confused this is impossible that 3 hard disk set as like this: multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS but one of them must known as multi(0)disk(1)rdisk(1)partition(1)\WINDOWS and etc. see this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLDR

Comment: fixmbr or fixboot or one of these solve your problem

Comment: I do no want to fix anything as its all fine. I want to know boot disk for each entry.

Comment: <3 (I have to fix a nasty mess up and was missing the bcdboot step)

Answer (score 1):

All 3 entries shown in bcdedit output point to same partition and disk.

To find out which partition (and disk) is mapped to c: you can use Windows DiskManagement or diskpart.exe on command prompt.